# How to use QueryInputs in UpdateByIndex

Tags: indexing, ravendb, updates

I'm about update a lot of documents in my Raven datastore. I intend to use UpdateByIndex to avoid having to load a lot of documents possibly even batched.

In order to search for the items to be updated I use the IndexQuery and Query but I'm wondering if I could use the QueryInputs property to send query parameter values?

I can't find any example using them in this context, is it possible and how would I do if possible.

**EDIT:**

Well after my initial steps trying to figure out how to use UpdateByIndex, the answer to why I would like to use something like QueryInputs in this context is

1. Readability of the code.
2. Transformations of types.

   ```
   var queryInputs = new Dictionary<string, RavenJToken>();
   queryInputs.Add("containerId", "containers/1");
   queryInputs.Add("latestTransition", new DateTime(2014, 12, 4));

   Session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex(
               new TaskByContainerAndTransitionDateIndex().IndexName,
               new IndexQuery
                   {
                       Query = ContainerId:\"{containerId}\" AND LatestTransition:[NULL TO {latestTransition}],
                       QueryInputs = queryInputs,
                   },
   ```

Instead of

```
var query = string.Format("ContainerId:\"{0}\" AND LatestTransition:[NULL TO {1}]",
                                      autoMove.FromContainer.Id,
                                      DateTools.DateToString(itemsOlderThan, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE));
```

Maybe not a strong case here but I was mostly exploring the API and wondering if it could be used.

Comment: Do you have an example of why QueryInput would be useful? I've never tried, so interested to see your use case.

Comment: Updated the question with example